# A\B test and sample size calculate for time data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, z-test

I am doing a statistical test (analysis) for the following case:

As part of a product aimed at improving the quality and speed of code writing for developers,
we have implemented a new feature that should make code review faster.

- Checking the time for code reviews in these groups :

1. Before the implementation date of the feature
2. After the implementation date of the feature

- Each group represents a vector of times in minutes
- The 2 sample distribution is unKnown (abnormal)
  I have tried several transformations to bring about a normal distribution, but without success.
  so I used Mann–Whitney U test.
- I use Python to write.

I have the following questions:

A. I would like to use A \ B TEST with time Data (shortening time). What can be done?

B. How do I know the sample size?

I tried to use calculators designed for A \ B TEST but they require me to input a conversion rate
I don't know how to do this in time data

Comment: You can use the formula 16σ^2 / delta^2, but you do need to know the variance in advance. Typically this is obtained from prior AB tests or analytics.

Comment: There is an explanation here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lIdpUHmouAAJ:gornbein.bol.ucla.edu/lecture%2520slides-sec%25205-power.pptx+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us The real issue you have is you are testing means not proportions. It isn't a time issue.

Comment: Can you explain this folmula:16σ^2 / delta^2? or add some example? Thanks

Comment: there's already one given